# HTML5 Canvas Arc shape depends on canvas width and height

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have two canvas elements with **different** height, and the `arc` is called with the same parameters (x,y,r,start,end) `arc(150,75,40,0,2*Math.PI)`.

One draws Eclipse and other draws Circle. How is Canvas height affecting the shape of the arc?

You can view the sample in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chandregowda/YwQqn/)

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
  <canvas id='one-canv'></canvas>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <canvas id='two-canv'></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#one-canv{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#FFFFBF;
}
#two-canv{
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#a3F77F;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById('one-canv');
var x_cont = x.getContext('2d');
x_cont.beginPath();
x_cont.arc(150,75,40,0,2*Math.PI);
x_cont.stroke();

var y = document.getElementById('two-canv');
var y_cont = y.getContext('2d');
y_cont.beginPath();
y_cont.arc(150,75,40,0,2*Math.PI);
y_cont.stroke();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add width and height attributes to your element(s):

```
<canvas id='one-canv' width=200 height=200></canvas>
```

If you want to do it programmatically please see the other answer

`width` and `height` affects the *bitmap* dimension while CSS width and height affects the *element* dimension - the two being "unrelated" in this context (no pun intended). The bitmap will be scaled to fit the element if the two isn't the same size.

For this reason try to avoid using CSS to specify canvas size (it has it purposes in some special cases).

I wrote a little more in-depth about setting canvas size <del>[here](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-properly-set-size-of-the-canvas-element/)</del> [archived link](http://web.archive.org/web/20131127123804/http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-properly-set-size-of-the-canvas-element/).

Comment: Thanks for the article! A pity, that the site went offline. (Once again, the Internet Archive saves the day: http://web.archive.org/web/20131127123804/http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-properly-set-size-of-the-canvas-element/ )

Answer (score 1):

The html canvas element starts out with a default size of 300 wide by 150 high.

If you use CSS to change that default width or height, the browser will "stretch" your circle's pixels to fit the new canvas size.

So using CSS to resize the canvas will usually distort your desired results.

Your two-canv is not distorted because you resized it in the same proportion to its default size.

The solution: resize the canvas element itself rather than using CSS.

*In javascript:*

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("one-canv");
canvas.width=200;
canvas.height=200;
```